# What's the origin of "this is going to come to a head"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms

I have used the phrases "This is going to come to a head" or "coming to a head". I think I know what they mean, I think I'm using them correctly.

So...where do these phrases come from? And, ahem, what *do* they (really) mean?

Comment: They come from the behavior of pimples. Study them carefully and you will see what it, ahem, really means.

Comment: What @John said. I thought there might be some less "yucky" etymology, but [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+to+a+head) entry for *come/bring to a head* really does say *These phrases allude to the **medical sense of head**, the tip of an abscess that is about to burst.*

Comment: By the way, I should mention that [TFD (The Free Dictionary)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/) now has its etymologies linked to the American Heritage Dictionary lists of [Proto-Indo-European roots](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European) and of [Semitic roots](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Semitic). These are the latest versions, now available to all word freaks. Enjoy,

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yeah, I kind of wish I hadn't asked. I'll never use this phrase again. I guess I'll start a question asking for alternatives!

Comment: *You* kinda wish you hadn't asked! So do ***I**!* I was perfectly happy using this idiom myself for decades, but now I might need to reconsider. Should I look for an even more circumlocutory expression such as ***erupting***, or just "tell it like it is", and start talking about critical situations [***pustulating**?*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pustulate)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Welp the layman understanding of the phrase is "come to head" = "come to be recognized"

Comment: @Pacerier: Idiomatic *come to a head* means *reach a crisis point*, which isn't exactly the same as *come to be recognized*. Practically everyone on earth should now recognise that climate change is happening, for example. But we won't be saying things have come to a head until something *really* critical happens (probably, something that causes millions of deaths very suddenly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Come to a head](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+to+a+head):  (TFD)

> - Fig. [for a problem] to reach a critical or crucial stage.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come%20to%20a%20head&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccome%20to%20a%20head%3B%2Cc0):  the expression 'come to a head' seems to be used from the 18th century and appears to refer to the culminating part of boil, a pimple or abscess that is likely to break.

[Come to a head](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/41/messages/659.html): The phrase finder refers to  MW:

> - a) **the part of a boil, pimple, or abscess at which it is likely to break**
> - b) culminating point of action : CRISIS -- events came to a head.

Comment: The phrase originated as a vulgarity in late latin. A popular guess about why "head" is used is the analogy of lettuce growing from a seed to completion —a head of lettuce.

Comment: @IanMacDonald -              Interesting..please provide evidence and make an answer.

Comment: So, the reference is not to a pot of boiling water about to spill over?

Comment: For some people.  Pimples are slow, boiling water is too fast. For others the topmost position of anything is its head, and _come to a head_ adds the concept of increasing differentiation between the head and the rest. That's way more semantic similarity than an idiom needs; consider _kick the bucket_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: the *boil* in definition (a) is referring to a *furuncle*, not boiling water.